# Problemas al intentar halar el valor de una etiqueta select en laravel

Tags: laravel, sql, querybuilder

tengo el problema que el controlador no esta halando bien los valores de mis SELECTs de la vista, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<form class="" action="/reportes/1" method="get">
  <div class="container col-6">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="seleccion" value="1"> Mensual</td>
          <td>
            <select class="form-control" name="anio">
              <option value="0">Selccione Año</option>
              <option value="2020">2020</option>
              <option value="2021">2021</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select class="form-control" name="mes">
              <option value="0">Selecciona Mes</option>
              <option value="1">Enero</option>
              <option value="2">Febrero</option>
              <option value="3">Marzo</option>
              <option value="4">Abril</option>
              <option value="5">Mayo</option>
              <option value="6">Junio</option>
              <option value="7">Julio</option>
              <option value="8">Agosto</option>
              <option value="9">Septiembre</option>
              <option value="10">Octubre</option>
              <option value="11">Noviembre</option>
              <option value="12">Diciembre</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="seleccion" value="2"> Por Persona</td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <select class="form-control" name="personal">
              <option value="">Selecciona Persona</option>
              @foreach($personal as $per)
              <option value="{{$per->id}}">{{$per->nombre}}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="seleccion" value="3"> Por Rango de Fechas</td>
          <td>
            <input type="date" name="desde" class="form-control">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="date" name="hasta" class="form-control">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Generar</button>
      <a href="{{action('HomeController@index')}}" class="btn btn-secondary">Regresar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
@endsection
```

en el controlador el siguiente codigo:

```
public function show(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->input('seleccion') == 1)
        {
            $reporte = DB::table('aportes as ap')
                        ->join('salidas as sa','ap.fecha','=','sa.fecha')
                        ->select('ap.cantidad as aportes','sa.cantidad as salidas')
                        ->where(DB::raw('year(ap.fecha)','="',$request->input('anio').'"'))
                        ->where(DB::raw('month(ap.fecha)','="',$request->input('mes').'"'))
                        ->get();
                        return $request;
            
        }
    }
```

al enviar el query a tosql me devuelve esto:

```
select `ap`.`cantidad` as `aportes`, `sa`.`cantidad` as `salidas` from `aportes` as `ap` inner join `salidas` as `sa` on `ap`.`fecha` = `sa`.`fecha` where year(ap.fecha) is null and month(ap.fecha) is null
```

pero al darle un return request al controlador me aparece esto:

```
{"seleccion":"1","anio":"2020","mes":"10","personal":null,"desde":null,"hasta":null}
```

tengo otros proyectos así con estos codigos y me dan error, la unica diferencia es que estoy utilizando DB::raw pero el query esta bien, ya que lo probé directamente en la base de datos.

espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 1):

En la consulta se ve que `$request->input('anio')` y `$request->input('mes')` están llegando como `NULL`, eso puede deberse a que estás utilizando mal el método `DB::raw()`. Pero fuera de eso, es mejor realizar tu consulta de la siguiente manera, utilizando `whereYear()` y `whereMonth()`:

```
$reporte = DB::table('aportes as ap')
          ->join('salidas as sa','ap.fecha','=','sa.fecha')
          ->select('ap.cantidad as aportes','sa.cantidad as salidas')
          ->whereYear('ap.fecha', $request->input('anio'))
          ->whereMonth('ap.fecha', $request->input('mes'))
          ->get();
```

Verifica que el formato de fecha que envías sea el mismo que tienes en la base de datos.

Tu error se encuentra en esta parte:

```
->where(DB::raw('year(ap.fecha)','="',$request->input('anio').'"'))
->where(DB::raw('month(ap.fecha)','="',$request->input('mes').'"'))
```

No es necesario utilizar `DB::raw()` dentro de un `where`, ya que siempre tienes la opción de utilizar `whereRaw()`. Si lo hacemos con whereRaw, quedaría así:

```
->whereRaw('year(ap.fecha) = ?', [$request->input('anio')])
->whereRaw('month(ap.fecha) = ?', [$request->input('mes')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te ocurre es que estás enviando el formulario por get, como lo muestras en este código:

```
<form class="" action="/reportes/1" method="get">
```

Por lo mismo, la sentencia `$request->input('mes')` te devuelve `null`.
Para obtener el parametro 'mes' desde el string de la url debes usar la sentencia
`$request->query('mes')`.

En este sitio (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#retrieving-input) puedes ver la documentación relacionada con esta respuesta.